# specflow.exe - 'libhostpolicy.so' not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, specflow

I'm trying to run the `specflow.exe` that comes with the nuget package on Linux, but I am getting the below error:

```
sashoalm@HP:~/.nuget/packages/specflow/2.4.1/tools$ dotnet specflow.exe
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/sashoalm/.nuget/packages/specflow/2.4.1/tools/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the /home/sashoalm/.nuget/packages/specflow/2.4.1/tools/specflow.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.
```

I found the file:

```
sashoalm@HP:~$ locate libhostpolicy.so
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.7/libhostpolicy.so
```

How can I make `specflow.exe` use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow <= 2.4 has no .NET Core support, so you can't execute the specflow.exe with `dotnet specflow.exe`.
You can try to use Mono to execute it. So it's `mono specflow.exe`